# Check if cookie exists else set cookie to Expire in 10 days 

Tags: javascript, cookies

Here is what I'm looking to do (pseudo-code):

Imagine the name of the cookie in the example is "visited" and it contains nothing.

```
if visited exists
then alert("hello again");
else
create visited - should expire in 10 days;
alert("This is your first time!")
```

How can I achieve this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You need to read and write `document.cookie`

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf("visited=") >= 0) {
  // They've been here before.
  alert("hello again");
}
else {
  // set a new cookie
  expiry = new Date();
  expiry.setTime(expiry.getTime()+(10*60*1000)); // Ten minutes

  // Date()'s toGMTSting() method will format the date correctly for a cookie
  document.cookie = "visited=yes; expires=" + expiry.toGMTString();
  alert("this is your first time");
}
```

Comment: `expires` is obsolete, by the way.

Comment: how do you expire a cookie if 'expires' is obsolete

Comment: @aamiri The newer alternative is `max-age=numseconds` to expire the cookie `numseconds` after it was set. See the other answer here for usage.

Comment: Doesn't really matter, but in sake of clarity I would use `> -1` rather than `>= 0`.

Comment: @SilverRingvee Totally agree. The solution above doesn't work for Chrome

Comment: @Michelangelo how for gods sake should >= 0 vs > -1 make that it is not working in chrome?

Comment: @Eugene Don't know. I am not a browser developer. The above **answer**  states to use >=0, i.e. equal or greater than zero. The only thing that worked in Chrome (few months ago) was to test if it was bigger than -1 for me. So I assume it was not sufficient to test if it was bigger than or equal to 0. Either way, totally agree to test for bigger than -1 to be sure, that was my point.

Comment: the only **failure** of this method is if there is cookie with same name:  **`blabla_visited`**

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski is the `=` supposed to be in `("visited=")` ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I guess so. This sets the cookie value as `visited=yes`, so it was intended as a string match against the entire `Cookie:` header and  could match with the `=` or without. I may have left it in just because the string `visited` might be more likely to occur in some other place in the cookie header and this needed to locate the string it explicitly set.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Don't make me explain code from 6 years ago, man! ;)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Haha! Ok thanks Michael. I'm just having this issue with cookies right now, which is something I haven't used in well over 10 years and given an XOR task; long story. I'm just not getting that thing to behave as it should. I've been at this for 3 solid days, believe it or not. But ..... persistance does (and hope) will pay off. Yet another "3 classic days on Google" *lol*

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I think I may finally got my "Eureka" moment ;-) To which I used part of your code. Just wanted to say thanks, *cheers*. Now I have to tackle the next part of my "XOR" problem. *lol!*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @MichaelBerkowski - Being persistant (which I am kind of a pitbull coder *lol!*) and debugging just paid off. Looking at HTML source (also), which many don't think of it as a debugging "tool", helped me to see where my JS was failing when pulled it in from an included PHP file and using cookies, which also needed to check if a file was empty or not, a real doozy of a project they wanted me to do. Now I can go on with the rest of my work; at long last. (Didn't meant to tie up comments here).

Answer (score 21):

```
if (/(^|;)\s*visited=/.test(document.cookie)) {
    alert("Hello again!");
} else {
    document.cookie = "visited=true; max-age=" + 60 * 60 * 24 * 10; // 60 seconds to a minute, 60 minutes to an hour, 24 hours to a day, and 10 days.
    alert("This is your first time!");
}
```

is one way to do it. Note that `document.cookie` is a magic property, so you don't have to worry about overwriting anything, either.

There are also [more convenient libraries to work with cookies](https://github.com/js-coder/cookie.js), and if you don’t need the information you’re storing sent to the server on every request, [HTML5’s `localStorage` and friends](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) are convenient and useful.

Comment: Chrome fix: `/(^|;\s?)visited=/`