# javascript if cookie exists execute

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

How can can i do a javascript if cookie exists execute, For example if i set a cookie "facebookpopchek" whit the value "NOpop"

I need a javascript that looks for the cookie like : if cookie "facebookpopchek" whit the value "NOpop" exist do nothing if not execute popup script.

popup script:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[Fans='*****'//]]></script>
<style>#fblikepop{background-color:#fff;display..............</style>
<script src='http://www.*****.com/facebookpop/jquery.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='http://www.*****.com/facebookpop/mbtlikebox2.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script language='javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function(){                       
        $().Fans({
            timeout: 30,
            wait: 0,
            url: 'http://www.facebook.com/*****',
            closeable: true     });
    });
//]]></script><div id='fbtpdiv'></div>
```

If some one know how to do this or has a example pleas let me know , Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [check cookie if cookie exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968196/check-cookie-if-cookie-exists)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you just read the cookie?

```
function n__readCookie(n__name)
{
    var n__nameEQ = n__name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++)
    {
        var c = ca[i];

        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') 
        {  c = c.substring(1,c.length);  }

        if (c.indexOf(n__nameEQ) == 0) 
        {  return c.substring(n__nameEQ.length,c.length);  }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then:

```
if(n__readCookie('facebookpopchek') != 'NOpop')
{
    //do popup
}
```

Comment: no i want : if cookie "facebookpopchek" exists DO "A" else DO "B"

Comment: got it : <script type="text/javascript">
if(document.cookie.search(/(^|;)facebookpopchek=/) > -1) {
    return false;
} else {
    alert("YES POP");
}
</script>