# How to check JSON parse method will return value before running the parse

Tags: javascript, json, cookies

So I'm using the `JSON.parse`-method to retrieve specific data from a cookie. However, if the cookie value does not exist, the input ends. Is there anyway to validate if this data is present before attempting to parse?

```
actual cookie data : "foo1":"1123","foo2":"332","foo3":"773" 

//function to retrieve cookie
function getCookie(name) {
    var re = new RegExp(name + "=([^;]+)");
    var value = re.exec(document.cookie);
    return (value !== null) ? unescape(value[1]) : null;
}
var cookie = getCookie("cookiename");
var cookieData = JSON.parse(cookie).foo4;
```

The code above will give the error unexpected end of input and terminate the program.

Comment: Console log `cookie` and see what you've got.

Comment: This will probably work: `var cookie = getCookie("cookiename") || '[]', which will be decoded into an empty array fi the cookie doesn't exist.`

Comment: *"actual cookie data : "foo1":"1123","foo2":"332","foo3":"773" "* If so, that's not JSON and will not parse. It needs `{` at the beginning and `}` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you can do, which work well together:

1. Use a default on `cookie` in case it's blank
2. Use error handling around the parse

E.g.:

```
var cookieData = null;
var foo4;
try {
    cookieData = JSON.parse(cookie || "null");
}
catch (e) {
}
foo4 = cookieData ? cookieData.foo4 : /*appropriate default here*/;
```

Or if you want the default even if `cookieData` is there, but it doesn't have `foo4` or `foo4` is any of the falsey values (`null`, `undefined`, `0`, `""`, `NaN`, or `false`), that last line would be:

```
foo4 = cookieData && cookieData.foo4 || /*appropriate default here*/;
```

Those use [JavaScript's curiously-powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html) (and it's similarly-powerful `&&` operator) to use `"null"` rather than `cookie` if the value of `cookie` is *falsey*. But it *also* uses error handling in case the cookie has complete nonsense in it.

Comment: hmm it still doesnt catch an error if foo4 doesnt actually exist in any form

Comment: @Ash: With the above you won't get an *error*. You'll get `undefined` in the `foo4` variable. I've added a further option that lets you supply the default more aggressively.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be asking how to check if the cookie exists, in which case this should help you -

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5968306/2198713

If it's not null then you can go ahead and try and parse it.

To make double sure it's OK, you can wrap your parse in a try block and catch a 'SyntaxError' exception - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse