# JavaScript check if a cookie exists via Name

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to do a simple IF statement to check if a specific Cookie exists:
I'm not looking to over complicate anything just something simple like

```
if (document.cookie.name("a") == -1 {
    console.log("false");
else {
    console.log("true");
}
```

What is this syntax for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check cookie if cookie exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968196/check-cookie-if-cookie-exists)

Answer (score 2):

first:

```
function getCookie(name) { 
  var cookies = '; ' + document.cookie; 
  var splitCookie = cookies.split('; ' + name + '='); 
  if (splitCookie.lenght == 2) return splitCookie.pop();
}
```

then you can use your if statement:

```
if (getCookie('a')) 
    console.log("false");
else 
    console.log("true");
```

should have work.

Comment: Nice one, any reason why the condition is `splitCookie.length == 2` and not just `splitCookie.length`?

Comment: Small typo in there at `splitCookie.lenght`

Comment: do you put the if statement inside the function, or outside the function?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help (w3schools documentation about javascript cookies) :

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

At **A Function to Get a Cookie**

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Please add the essential relevant parts of the linked content to your answer; see [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

this could help you:

```js
class Cookies {
  
  static exists(name) {
  
    return name && !!Cookies.get(name);
  }
  
  static set(name, value, expires = Date.now() + 8.64e+7, path = '/') {
    document.cookie = `${name}=${value};expires=${expires};path=${path};`;
  }
  
  static get(name = null) {
    const cookies = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie)
      .split(/;\s?/)
      .map(c => {
        let [name, value] = c.split(/\s?=\s?/);

        return {name, value}; 
      })
    ;
    
    return name 
      ? cookies.filter(c => c.name === name).pop() || null
      : cookies
    ;
  }
}
```