# Check if cookie __RequestVerificationToken is present

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am getting a famous asp mvc error:

> The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.

I am only getting this error when deploying my site to **`godaddy` server** and only on the **login page**. However, all it takes is for me to refresh the page and the error is gone.

Thus, i trying to figure out how to check if this cookie exists and run:

```
location.reload(true);
```

if cookie does not exist, which i think will solve the problem.

So i tried to use:

```
if(!$.cookie('__RequestVerificationToken')){
    location.reload(true);
}
```

But the `cookie` is always `undefined` and the above code keeps reloading the page.

I have checked almost every SO question relating to this problem and cannot seem to find the answer.

Comment: the cookie name is usually something like `__RequestVerificationToken_L0F3ZXNvbWV...` so you have the wrong name

Answer (score 0):

Well, `$.cookie` is not built-in to jQuery. It requires a plugin. If you don't have that plugin, that's going to come back as `undefined` and testing `!undefined` is always going to be true. As a result, I would assume you found that code somewhere, assumed it was part of jQuery, and didn't bother to include the plugin that actually makes it work as a result. Additionally, that syntax and the associated plugin has been deprecated in favor of the [JavaScript Cookie project](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie), so use that rather than the old jQuery Cookie plugin.

Comment: i did include `"~/Scripts/global/jquery.cokie.min.js"` in my login page

Comment: i also tested it by creating a test cookie and checking if it exists with the same code

Comment: Is that a direct paste? You spelled "cookie" as "cokie".

Comment: yes it is, i checked the file exists with name: `jquery.cokie.min.js`

Comment: so just a type in file name

Comment: Also tried to get the cookie via javascript: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968196/check-cookie-if-cookie-exists. I am getting a null

Answer (score 0):

Check your Web.config and if present comment the following line

httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true".