# Javascript checking for cookie values

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a temporary login script, that checks a password, assigns a cookie, and then redirects the user to a new page. On the console page, I have code that checks if the cookie is set to `true`. If it is, it deletes it and continues. If it isn't, it redirects the user back to the homepage. I got all the code in place, but it doesn't work! Here's some more important info:

- The cookie is called `login`
- the logged in cookie is set to `true`
- The cookie sets properly, it's a problem with the console page's code.
  Here's my code:

```js
function getCookie(name) {
    var dc = document.cookie;
    var prefix = name + "=";
    var begin = dc.indexOf("; " + prefix);
    if (begin == -1) {
        begin = dc.indexOf(prefix);
        if (begin != 0) return null;
    }
    else
    {
        begin += 2;
        var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
        if (end == -1) {
        end = dc.length;
        }
    }
    // because unescape has been deprecated, replaced with decodeURI
    //return unescape(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
    return decodeURI(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
} 

function doSomething() {
    var myCookie = getCookie("login");

    if (myCookie == true) {
alert("Logged in for one session!");
        document.cookie = "username=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;";       

    }
    else {
alert("Login Failed. Redirecting...");
window.location.assign("https://www.code-u.org/")
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the console error

Comment: well did you add console.log lines to see why it is and is not working? eg `console.log('myCookie', myCookie, myCookie==true);` And FYI, the cookie value would be a string, not a boolean. Does it go into the if? does it go into the else?

Comment: It may be noteworthy that this question is this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5968306/114900

Comment: I dont have the console error, Stefano
I know that, msanford, I used that code, but i'm having prioblems with it.
How would i add console.log, epascarello?
I changed it to "true" instead of true according to your suggestion, and it didn't work!

Comment: Can you first do alert(myCookie) before if (myCookie == true) { to see what myCookie value is?

Comment: Anyways it seems your getCookie(...) parsing is completely screwed up.

Answer (score 0):

Two years too late to help you, but it's because this widely copypasted `getCookie` has an error in it.

Namely it does not work if the cookie set is the first cookie in `document.cookies`, because when the branch `if (begin == -1)` is taken, `end` is never set.

The solution would be to replace the `getCookie` with another implementation.