# How can i save the dark mode value in browsers ( using jquery )

Tags: javascript, jquery

the idea is I've a dark mode,i done with it ,but the problem ,when i reload the page the dark mode gone

this is **HTML** code

```
<input type="checkbox" id="darkMode" name="">
```

and this is **js** code ( with this way doesn't run )

```
var ele = 'body';

  $('#darkMode').on('click',function(){

      if(  $('#darkMode').prop('checked') ){

        $(ele).addClass('dark-mode');

        // here i wanna save the value of darkMode in browser 
        $.cookie('darkMode', 'dark', { expires: 7, path: '/' });

      }else{

        $(ele).removeClass('dark-mode');

      }

  });
```

thanks !

Comment: This code will save a cookie, but on load of page, are you checking for this cookie and loading value from it? It won't happen on its own.

Comment: Alternative to using cookies => [window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if($.cookie('darkMode')){
    $(ele).addClass('dark-mode');
    $('#darkMode').prop('checked',true)
  }
});
```

It will check if the cookie exist and if it does then set the darkmode.

**Edit**

if you want to remove the `cookie` when you uncheck the checkbox, then use

```
$.removeCookie('darkMode', {
  path: '/'
});
```

[FiddleTest](https://jsfiddle.net/7ho59sj2/)

Comment: In your jsfiddle, you will have troubles if the user uncheck the input and reload the page.

Comment: @Dwhitz true, but currently is not apart of the OP question. I will add it in a sec

Comment: thanks you so much > but i have this code (  $('.edit-button,.ok-button').toggle(); ) for switching between to image > where i should put it to save also like darkmode ( if you don't got it ) i have two image logo and bgfor website it's related with the dark mode when i click dark mode he should save the dark mode and image for dark mode together >????
and thank u so much for your help

Comment: @rabeea I only have the code you posted, and neither you code or text said anything about two image logos, but happy it helps you

Answer (score 0):

You can read `cookie` of the document, check if `darkMode` property is present using regular expression and add `dark-mode` class to the `body`

```
if(document.cookie.match(/^(.*;)?\s*darkMode\s*=\s*[^;]+(.*)?$/)) {
  $('body').addClass('dark-mode');
}
```

Comment: you should always add an explanation to why your answer will work. Also if you just copy paste the answer then it's a good idea to link to the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25617724/2943218