# How to check cookies are enabled in first visit on site

Tags: php, cookies

I saw some examples cookies enabled and disabled but all of them giving disabled in first time visit.

I tried this example: https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_cookie5

or

http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-check-if-cookies-are-enabled-using-PHP.php

But see, first time always giving the message cookies are disabled!

[image]

Comment: Cookies are in the browser. Use Javascript to check if cookies exist. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968196/check-cookie-if-cookie-exists

Comment: Im receiving a BOT attack, they disabled javascript and cookies. I have to do something on Backend in this case...

Comment: You should add recaptcha to prevent yourself from the bots. On the backend, you cannot usually distinguish between a bot and a normal user.

Comment: Maybe you can set the cookie and then redirect with a parameter and check for the cookie there?

Comment: Msg, i thinked about it. It makes a infinite loop when cookies are disabled. Umair, im using recaptcha in forms, this case is not a form.

Comment: If cookie is not set and parameter is, just die.

Answer (score 0):

Answering because I can't comment, but try this answer linked here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6663901/11261849 . Try the javascript method described there and see if that one works on first visit. Checking for cookies enabled in PHP can be hard to check for the first time because the page usually needs to be refreshed in order to check for them being enabled.