# Javascript: unique if condition per page & cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Here's the thing:

I have 2 separate pages with some content hidden which only show up after a certain time is spent on my page (to sync with what I say on my video). This is [Page A](https://brunopicinini.com/sl/marketing-para-profissionais) and this is [Page B](https://brunopicinini.com/sl/marketing-para-empreendedores)

On that page, you will see a video. If you reload the page, you will see a green button popping up below. That happens because I have the following script at my page footer to set a cookie and remember that "from 2nd visit onwards, always show the content".

Here's the script:

```
<script>if(/(^|;)s*cookie_lp=/.test(document.cookie)){var divs=document.querySelectorAll("div.thrv_content_reveal");[].forEach.call(divs,function(e){e.style.display="block"})}else document.cookie="cookie_lp=true; max-age=31536000";</script>
```

The script itself is very simple: it just checks whether that cookie returns a true value. If so, show content. If not, then set cookie.

(At least that's what I believe it does. It wasn't me who coded.)

The problem is that if I first go to Page A, the button is hidden. If I then immediately visit Page B, the button will show up, even though it's the first visit to that *specific* page (because the cookie is set in the user's browser).

So what I need is just to adapt the script to make it unique and work on a **per page** basis. Meaning:

If I access Page A for the 1st time, button is hidden. Second time, button show up. BUT… if I access Page B after that, button should still be hidden (1st visit to that page).

I've tried changing the cookie name to an unique page for each page (e.g.: `cookie_lp_pageA`), but that created a different problem which I'm not sure why (the button would never show regardless of how many visits).

I believe it's something small which I'm not seen (I'm no coder, just a curious guy). So maybe someone will spot it quickly.

Thanks!

Comment: Your problem with your 2 cookie approach may be as shown here, please try offered solution to solve it https://stackoverflow.com/a/47305680/10634638

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that's a bit too much for me. My knowledge on that is limited. So I can't really make sense and adapt it like that. Thanks for the link though!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using local storage https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp

This code should work on either page A or B:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function visitCounter(pageID) {
  if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage['page'+pageID]) {
      localStorage['page'+pageID] = parseInt(localStorage['page'+pageID]) + 1;     
      document.getElementById('button1').innerText = "Show";
    } else {
      localStorage['page'+pageID] = 1;
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have visited " + localStorage['page'+pageID] + " time(s).";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p><button type="button" id="button1">Hide</button></p>

<div id="result"></div>

<p>Close the browser tab (or window), and try again, and the counter will continue to count (is not reset).</p>


<script>
   var url  = window.location.pathname;
   var pageID = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1); //pageA, pageB
   visitCounter(pageID);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok! I'll try that. Thanks!